# SetProperty ref - Object is null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, prism

I guess it's just a really small thing I'm overlooking, but I can't figure out why this won't work...

```
public ObservableCollection<UserDto> Users
{
    get
    {
        return _users;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _users, value);
    }
}
```

Now when I set `Users` like this, it will still be `null`:

```
pageItem.Object.Users = new ObservableCollection<UserDto>();
```

I can get it working if I use a "standard" Property like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<UserDto> Users { get; set; }
```

But why does it not work with `SetProperty(ref variable, value)`?

### EDIT

I'm using **.NET Framework 4.5**.

I also debugged the code. In the first screenshot, `_users` is `null` and I try to set a `value` which contains one `UserDto`:

```
var newUsers = new ObservableCollection<UserDto>();
var user = new UserDto();
newUsers.Add(user);
pageItem.Object.Users = newUsers;  // This steps into the setter
```

[image]

After this step tho, `_users` is still `null`:

[image]

Comment: What is `SetProperty`? **Edit** I see, you should add relevant tags like wpf, mvvm and prism

Comment: I assume you mean this [`SetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736263(v=pandp.50).aspx)? The documentation says it takes a reference to a property, but you give it one to a field, not sure if that causes issues.

Comment: @Mats391, You can't make a reference to a C# property, you will have to make it a reference to a field, but perhaps the documentation means a field holding a reference to an observable property?

Comment: Which Framework version are you using?

Comment: @dymanoid .NET 4.5. I also added some information about the debugging

Comment: Are there some event handlers for the `PropertyChanged` event? Maybe someone resets the property value back to `null`. This looks really strange.

Comment: And one more thought: are you sure you're inspecting the same object? (Maybe these are two independent instances of your container class.) Use "Object ID" in VS debugger to ensure that.

Comment: @dymanoid While I didn't find a solution with the Object ID, it pointed me to the right track... `pageItem` is a `Mock` and for some reason, `SetProperty` won't work for a `Mock`. Guess I need to learn more :)

Comment: This is a complete waste of time.  ObservableCollection properties should be read only.  Set them in the constructor, and alter them during execution.  They implement change notification that bindings use to know when the collection changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a a `Mock` (http://www.developerhandbook.com/unit-testing/writing-unit-tests-with-nunit-and-moq/) for `PageItem`:

```
Mock<GroupCarouselViewPageItem> pageItem = new Mock<GroupCarouselViewPageItem>();
```

If I remove the Mock and just use a `GroupCarouselViewPageItem` as the type, it will work... Not 100% sure why, but it solved the problem.

```
GroupCarouselViewPageItem i = new GroupCarouselViewPageItem();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`SetProperty` is not a built-in method. If the `_users` field is still `null` after calling this method, the method is obviously incorrectly implemented.

You could take a look at how the `SetProperty` method is actually implemented in Prism and compare this implementation to yours:

```
protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (Equals(storage, value)) return false;

    storage = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);

    return true;
}
```

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs

For testing purposes, you could paste in the above implementation into your class, give the method another name and call this one instead of the current `SetProperty` method.

If you are using Prism's version of `SetProperty` it should work though. If it doesn't you should *prove* your point: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You should create `pageItem` like this:

```
Mock<GroupCarouselViewPageItem> pageItem = new Mock<GroupCarouselViewPageItem>() 
{
   CallBase = true;
};
```

`SetProperty` is virtual method in Prism library in `BindableBase` class, so if you create mock of `GroupCarouselViewPageItem`, non of the virtual method will be called. In particular `SetProperty` method that change the value of `_users` field.
Set `CallBase = true` will cause that all virtual implementation will be called.